# Is it possible to isolate some controls in a separate process in WPF?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, user-interface, process

For example, in [Firefox](https://www.mozilla.com/en-US/firefox/3.6.4/releasenotes/), there is a plugin-container.exe which isolates Adobe Flash, Apple Quicktime or Microsoft Silverlight plugins so that when they crash, the browser does not crash.

Is it possible to achieve something similar in WPF? Like loading some user-customized controls (analogous to plugins in browser) in a separate process, and make them start their threads (like click handler etc) in that process so that when their code throws an exception, the host application doesn't crash?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create a WPF "control" that is run in an external process](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1121934/create-a-wpf-control-that-is-run-in-an-external-process)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming I have understood your question properly I think this might be considered as a duplicate of

[Create a WPF "control" that is run in an external process](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1121934/808940)

The canonical term for this would be "out of process" so you will havemore success if you use this when searching for further information.

These links should get you started

[Hosting WPF UI cross-thread and cross-process](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/changov/archive/2009/10/26/hosting-wpf-ui-cross-thread-and-cross-process.aspx)

[Hosting Out-of-process ActiveX control in WPF](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/acbbb4ae-5d31-404b-91b8-919493947e7b/)

[AppDomain Isolated WPF Add-Ins](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/clraddins/archive/2007/08/06/appdomain-isolated-wpf-add-ins-jesse-kaplan.aspx)